# Informatica: Combine data from two tables, eliminate duplicates

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have two tables:

## Table A

Col 1, Col 2, Col 3, Col 4

This has 100 records

## Table B

Col 1, Col 2, Col 4

This table has 75 records but may have different records from **Table A.**

I also have another Table C which works as a lookup for Col 3 from **Table A.**

Now I want to write a new table with a layout of Table A using both **Table A** and B records, eliminate duplicates and populate Col 3 values using **Table C.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: After pulling columns from Table A and B into SQ, how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can union the records from A and B and do a distinct using sorter or aggregator.

The mapping would be something like this.

```
SQ(A)-------------\
                   \
                     Union ---> Sorter(Distinct)----> Target
                    /
SQ(B)--> Lookup(C)-/
```

Comment: I will check. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are new to Informatica. If all the tables which you are referring is in same database, then why don't you use SQL Override, that will increase the performance of the mapping as well.